# getTitle() in News.class.php in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i have table News:

```
id   | title  | body
1    | title1 | body1
2    | title2 | body2
```

etc.

I have

News.class.php
and
NewsTable.class.php

i would like edit method **getTitle()**.
In News.class.php i add:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title . "aa"; //line 35
}
```

but i have error:

Notice: Undefined property: News::$title in localhost/new/lib/model/doctrine/News.class.php on line 35

i if change for:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->getTitle() . "aa"; //line 35
}
```

then site not show.

if change:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->body . "aa"; //line 35
}
```

this work OK! 
How can i fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->get('title')`. That gets the title from the Doctrine model class. :)

```
public function getTitle() {
  return $this->get('title').'aa';
}
```

Comment: if i use $this->get('title') then i have all white page. in page source is NULL

Comment: but if i use for example in function getTitle() - $this->get('body') this work OK